# How to use react onScroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Query query={getArticlesQuery} pollInterval={0} notifyOnNetworkStatusChange={true}>

          {
            ({ data, networkStatus, error, loading, refetch }) => {
              if (networkStatus === 4) { return <Reloading /> }
              if (loading) { return <Loading /> }
              if (error) { return <Error /> }

              //Received required data from query response
              const articles = data.articles;


              return (
                <div onScroll={(e)=>{console.log("test")}}>
                  <div className="refetchbutton">
                    <button onClick={() => { refetch() }}>Refetch!</button>
                  </div>
                <AllPosts allArticles={articles} onScroll={(e)=>{console.log("test")}}/>


                </div>

              )

            }
          }

        </Query>
```

Allposts.js

```
class AllPosts extends React.Component{

    render(){

    let articles_p = this.props.allArticles;

    return(
        articles_p.map((article) => { return <Post key={article.id} data={article} /> })
    );

}
}
```

I have an Apollo query component which receives data as a response.
This response is passed to another component called "AllPosts" which returns an array of the component "Post". However, they are around 122articles and in the middle section of the image attached with the post i have to scroll continuously till the last post. I want to use onScroll to notify when i am scrolling on an element. The code i have currently doesn't seem to be working, does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Afaik, only the container of the topmost element that moves receives the onScroll event. By default, that's `window`.